# Ubuntu 20.04: File explorer takes very long to open

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, nautilus

For about one month now I have the problem that all tasks related to opening the file explorer in Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) take very long. Whether I directly try to use the file explorer or via a menu (e.g. upload a file through a browser file picker). I usually takes around 10 seconds. This makes using Ubuntu impossible and I really consider switching back to windows to get stuff done.

I have since twice reinstalled Ubuntu after formatting the hard drive but the problem remains. I would be glad if someone could help me debug this problem.

One thing to note: Once I opened the file explorer and keep the window open, a second window opens with the regular speed.

If I run `nautilus` from the command line I get the following output (in German)

```bsh
Error creating proxy: Fehler beim Aufruf von StartServiceByName für org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Nautilus-Share-Message: 08:22:40.932: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Kindprozess »net« konnte nicht ausgeführt werden (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Do you have any network drives, shared folders or even USB connected devices?

Comment: Yes I have two external drives connected as I run automated backups using a cronjob. But even if I unplug them I have this problem.